# Automatically download Zotero group library

Tags: reference-managers

[Zotero group libraries](https://www.zotero.org/groups/) provide a way to share and collaboratively manage bibliographies. I would like to use an existing group library as BibTeX references file (or any other format supported by pandoc) without having to install and configure Zotero and manually export BibTeX. How can I download all references from a Zotero group library via command line?

Comment: I haven't tried what you want to accomplish, but there's zotero-cli for the command line: https://github.com/jbaiter/zotero-cli and various python packages.

Comment: Just FWIW, there's a new Zotero automation software library: https://github.com/hack-r/pyserpZotero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the machine you are working on does not have Zotero installed, the easiest way to export a group library is through the [Zotero web interface](https://www.zotero.org/groups/) - when logged in just choose the group library, select all items and use the Export button with the format of your choice.

[image: screenshot of Zotero Export]

If by "automatically" and "command line" you mean that you want to be able to non-interactively run a script that exports a Zotero library to BibTeX using a computer that doesn't have Zotero on it, I'm not aware of a tool that does that for you, but the [Zotero Web API](https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/web_api/v3/start) is published and documented. Exporting items is just a command line call such as

```
curl "https://api.zotero.org/groups/$ID/items?format=bibtex&limit=100" > references.bib
```

where `$ID` must be replaced by your Zotero group id.

Comment: Thanks, that's enough to start with! I keep the question unanswered until there is a more detailed description of how to use the Web API.